# JS insert page break into a long table

Tags: javascript, css

I have a long table that gets created by JavaScript . and I was wondering is there a way to insert page break inside the table for every 10 row. I noticed that page break will be dropped if its inline style for html row.
do I need to create multiple table?
here is the table 
https://jsfiddle.net/j1pqtjtv/3/

```
<table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" class="itemsTable">
            <tbody><tr class="itemsHeader">

                <th align="left">Information</th>
                <th align="left" style="width:100px;">Price</th>
                <th align="left" style="width:200px;">price</th>


            </tr>
            </tbody><tbody id="divDataLocalStorage" style="font-size:26px;">

                <tr>

                </tr>

            <tr><td class="item"></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$59.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$59.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$67.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$67.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$69.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$76.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$76.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$78.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$88.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$99.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$109.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$114.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$119.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$125.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$133.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$135.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$141.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$143.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$146.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$149.95</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$152.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$154.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$166.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$183.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$188.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$188.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$197.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$270.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$278.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$291.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$351.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$353.13</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$362.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$378.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$474.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$488.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$511.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$596.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$613.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$630.77</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$642.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$648.57</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$663.08</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$695.14</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$731.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$753.00</td><td>$50.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$788.00</td><td>$100.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$792.74</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$903.71</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$965.98</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,137.42</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,210.77</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,281.54</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,315.71</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,335.22</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,513.69</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,568.34</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,765.62</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$1,772.31</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,010.03</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,085.02</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,106.15</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,199.35</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,270.52</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,461.45</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xxM</td><td>$2,633.85</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,669.63</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$2,854.25</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$3,008.51</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$3,104.62</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$3,316.92</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$3,530.77</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$6,947.69</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$10,209.63</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$11,866.15</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="item">xx</td><td>$13,173.85</td><td>$0.00</td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: just insert an empty row every 10th row via JS.

`<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`, for example.

Comment: @Timmy is that same thing as page break?

Comment: it most certainly is not, my apologies I completely misread what you were asking. It's rather late here lol =)

Comment: @Timmy :) I appreciate your respond :)

Comment: Please clean up your example. There's no need to include the base64 images and I can't see any element with the id `printArea`. It would be easier to diagnose without all the noise.

Comment: @SpliFF I fixed the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't introduce an element like `<br>` into the mix because you can't control the height of that gap without writing more code and because it's unnecessary when you can just manipulate the CSS to achieve what you want. You simply make sure your rows are `display:block`, and then you do the following JS:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

for (var i = 0; i <= rows.length-1; i += 10 ) {

    rows[i].style.marginBottom = '50px';

};
```

You'll have to modify the selector a bit to fit your needs, but that's basically it.

**[EDIT]**

Remove the inline-styling on your `th` and do something like in the CSS:

```
 tr {
   display: block;}

 th,
 td {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;}

 th:nth-child(1), 
 td:nth-child(1) {
   width: 50%;}

 th:nth-child(2), 
 td:nth-child(2) {
   width: 20%;}

 th:nth-child(3), 
 td:nth-child(3) {
   width: 20%;}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the respond. if I make the rows display block it throws off all my content alignments . is there any reason for display block

Comment: @benji_r Margin only works on elements that don't have table display types, which yours currently does, so the idea was to change the display of the row so margin could be applied, but I see how that messed up the cells within. One way to fix that would be to set the `td` to be `display:inline-block` and then set the widths of each column. It's an extra step, but it will work.